# Issue with running a PDO statement from a $.ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, pdo

Hey guys I have the following ajax call:

```
function sendUserfNotes()
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: '/pcg/popups/getNotes.php',
    data:
    {
        'nameNotes': notes_name.text(),
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $('#notes_body').text(response.the_notes);
        alert(response.the_notes);
        //$('#notes_body').html(data);
    }
});
```

Once this runs and it goes to this file:
  .......

```
try {  
  # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL  
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

}  
catch(PDOException $e) { 
    echo "I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't do that.";  
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);   
}

$username_notes = $_POST['nameNotes'];

$sql = "SELECT notes FROM csvdata WHERE username = :username";
$getmeminfo = $DBH->prepare($sql);
$getmeminfo->execute(array(':username' => $username_notes));
$row = $getmeminfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$notes = $row['notes'];

$returnArray = array( 'the_notes' => $row['notes']);

echo json_encode($returnArray);
$DBH = null;
```

Now in here once the json array is returned the `$('#notes_body').text(response.the_notes);` will change a div with the response that was returned, but my issue is I cannot get it to return back.  It is always null?

I am not to sure what is wrong so if you would be so kind and to give me some of your time :)

David

UPDATE:

So one thing is I have tested the pdo statement on it's own and it works.

if I were to just give $username_notes a direct name like "BillCosby" it would return the right value for that person.

Comment: There is no such thing like "issue with PDO in $.ajax". PDO is server side while $.ajax is client side.

Comment: *You* need to figure out if the PHP code doesn't work (run the script directly, use $_GET temporarily), or if the jQuery insertion fails.

Comment: I did and it works like lets say I just gave the pdo statement the names dirrectly in the file to be called and in itself, it would work.  I would get the right value.  Its just when I am coming from a $.ajax it doesnt work, or seem to.

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes but the $.ajax function calls the .php file that contains the pdo so that should work, no?

Comment: Put some debug in your PHP.  Echo out your $_POST, then log that into your browser console in your ajax success function.  Also, you don't have a fail function.  Also you need to consider using the more modern jquery .done() promise pattern.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing like "issue with PDO in $.ajax". PDO is server side while $.ajax is client side.

> It's like the pdo statement does not even run?

Nobody knows.
Nobody have access to your code but you.
So, you have to answer yourself. Debug your code.

For the client-side debugging Firebug is priceless.
Open it's Net tab and see if there was an HTTP call at all. If it was - did it return anything?
Open Console and see if there are any errors.

Comment: The pdo statement does run if I am to do it on itself....like take a file and run the code, the pdo by itself.  It will return the correct value.