# Issue with retrieving a parameter from a $.ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, pdo

Hey guys I have the following $.ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/pcg/popups/getNotes.php',
        data:
        {
            'nameNotes': notes_name.text(),

        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#notes_body').text(response.the_notes);
            alert(response.the_notes);

        }
)};
```

Now focus on the `data:`  lets say I sent 'BillCosby'.  That will be sent over to the file specified and  i have this inside that file:

```
$username_notes = $_POST['nameNotes'];
```

Now lets say I was to just have $username_notes return in the json like this...

```
$returnArray = array( 'the_notes' => $username_notes );

echo json_encode($returnArray);
```

This would work and the response would be BillCosby.  Now with that out of the way, when I try to get a value for BillCosby from my MySQL database using PDO it will return null....Before I show the code for the whole file I just want to make clear that the PDO works perfect,  if I were to give the variable $username_notes the direct value of 'BillCosby' I would run through the database perfect, it only returns null if I have the $_POST['nameNotes']; in front.

getNotes.php:

```
$username_notes = $_POST['nameNotes'];

grabNotes($username_notes);



function grabNotes($xusername)
{   
    .....

    $newUser = $xusername;

    try {  
      # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL  
      $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
      $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    }  
    catch(PDOException $e) { 
        echo "I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't do that.";  
        file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);   
    }

    $sql = "SELECT notes FROM csvdata WHERE username = :username";
    $getmeminfo = $DBH->prepare($sql);
    $getmeminfo->execute(array(':username' => $newUser));
    $row = $getmeminfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $notes = $row['notes'];

    $returnArray = array( 'the_notes' => $row['notes'],);

    echo json_encode($returnArray);

    $DBH = null;

}
```

So my question is, why can I not get the return value back from the PDO statement?  It will work perfect if I told the PDO statement the name - 'BillCosby' inside the file that the $.ajax file calls to.  But it will not work and returns null if I get the value through $_POST from the $.ajax.  the funny thing is I can return the same value that was sent in.

Thanks for your time guys!

Comment: It's weird you usage `$username`. It even looks like it is shadowing another variable

Comment: Try trimming it -> `$username_notes = trim( $_POST['nameNotes'] );`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue with running a PDO statement from a $.ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800559/issue-with-running-a-pdo-statement-from-a-ajax-call)

Comment: How come trimming it worked?

Comment: There you go, spaces in the text() you're getting from the page. Since I'm right, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: @moonwave99 it kinda is, it's just no one was responding because they thought I was trying to do something else....my question was not as clear either.

Comment: Sweet thanks...@adeneo you wanna put the answer down so I can give to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try trimming it :

```
$username_notes = trim( $_POST['nameNotes'] );
```

Sometimes spaces in the string will cause this sort of error, and they can be hard to spot.

Comment: @DavidBiga - sure, just happy to help?

Answer (score 0):

I often have to add the ?callback=?. So your JQuery ajax request will look like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: '/pcg/popups/getNotes.php?callback=?',
    data:
    {
        'nameNotes': notes_name.text(),

    },
    success: function(response) {
        $('#notes_body').text(response.the_notes);
        alert(response.the_notes);

    }
)};
```

Also, preferrably you'd use the jQuery.getJSON method.