# Retrieving query parameters from a $.GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parameters, xmlhttprequest

I realize that this a variant of [Issue with retrieving a parameter from a $.ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801320/issue-with-retrieving-a-parameter-from-a-ajax-call) but I'd like to try and solve this with JavaScript or jQuery alone. The above question's solution uses PHP $_REQUEST to convert the parameters from a PHP variable to a JS variable. Ugly and not well-written uniform code!

When issuing a $.GET, if the target script is not a PHP file (say an HTM, instead), there should be a method to retrieve the query parameters. However, every solution I've come across for pulling them is not meant for a $.GET, as the **XHR URL** may be `http://mysite/forms/form.processScript.htm`, the actual **WINDOW URL** is `http://mysite/index.php`.  Each solution, including *PURL* and the various *getUrlVars* scripts, only pull query parameters from the **WINDOW URL**, resulting in *undefined* variables.

If I were more familiar with the internal XHR process, I could probably work through this on my own. Unfortunately, until now, that has not been a high priority.

Comment: So you wrote JavaScript to make a request to a URL and you want to know (in your JS) what that URL is? Shouldn't you know that already?

Comment: No, I don't want the URL, I want the query parameters.

Comment: Which are part of the URL.

Comment: Everything after the "?".

Comment: But since you know the URL, why are you worrying about XHR? (And its after the `?` but before the `#` if there is one)

Comment: I'm calling an *htm* from a PHP script using $.get and want to retrieve the data sent to that *htm* for further processing via another $.get call to a second PHP script.  The interim *htm* script is unable to see the query params without the PHP $_REQUEST => JS variable conversion.

Comment: The interim `htm` *document* is just a document. If you want to modify it, then the JS will be running in the context of the main page.

Comment: Apparently, I'm not explaining it very well. The interim `htm` contains it's own JS (including a dialog box with a form) which performs another action. This new action relies on some of the data passed from to this `htm` but I am unable to see that data if I don't use $_REQUEST.

Comment: @DevlshOne Quentin is right here.  The `htm` page is retrieved by the `$.get` call and is not run when retrieved.  If the retrieved page contains js, it can then be run in the context of the current page, but iwll only have access to the URL of the current page.  It has no knowledge of the fact that it was initially retrieved from a different URL.  However, as Quentin said earlier, the current page made the initial request, so clearly the current page already knows the values of the query parameters without reading from the url.  If nothing else, you can use a global variable on the page.